# Поворот персонажа по оси X в направлении мышки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу реализовать поворот персонажа по оси X в направлении мышки (ось Y)? Персонаж как бы "смотрит" в сторону курсора. Учитываться должна только ось Y мышки. Скрипт будет присвоен части, которая и должна поворачиваться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Mathf.Atan2(-(mouse.y-taget.y), mouse.x-target.x)/Mathf.PI*180f;`

Answer (score 0):

В декартовой системе угол можно вычислить так:

```
angle = atan2(mouseY - persY, mouseX - persX)
```